# CMake - How can I pass the windows SDK version to an ExternalProject built with msbuild?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, msbuild, windows-10, external-project

I have a CMake project which has an external dependency (Crypto++). The external project has a `vcxproj` file provided, so in order to add it to the build process, I added it like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(CryptoPP
    SOURCE_DIR ${CRYPTOPP_SRC_DIR}

    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""

    BUILD_COMMAND "${MSBUILD_EXE}" 
        "/p:OutDir=<BINARY_DIR>/bin/$<CONFIG>/"
        "/p:IntDir=<BINARY_DIR>/obj/$<CONFIG>/"
        "/p:Configuration=$<CONFIG>"
        "/p:Platform=${CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME}"
        "<SOURCE_DIR>/${CRYPTOPP_PROJECT}"

    INSTALL_COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E make_directory <INSTALL_DIR>/lib
            COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy <BINARY_DIR>/bin/$<CONFIG>/cryptlib${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} <INSTALL_DIR>/lib
)
```

This worked fine until I started using Windows 10. Now I'm getting this error: `The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution"`.

I tried passing the SDK version from CMake, using [the only related CMake variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/variable/CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION.html) I could find, by adding this flag to msbuild:

```
"/p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=${CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION}"
```

However, I'm still getting the same error. I tried displaying the value of the `CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION` variable, and it always seems empty.

Modifying the dependency `vcxproj` is not an option. I don't know in advance what SDK version whoever needs to build the project has installed, so that's not an option.

I can't find any way to obtain and pass the SDK version to the external project build, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to set the `platform toolset`. I was building my CMake project with `v100` so it doesn't need an SDK version. Because I didn't configure the `platform toolset` for the external project, it used the one set in the project which was the latest (v141) which needed an SDK version.

So adding this flag fixed my setup:

```
"/p:PlatformToolset=${CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET}"
```